# Why was a dash placed directly after a semicolon?

Tags: punctuation

In *Frankenstein* by Mary Shelley, there was a semicolon accompanied by a dash placed immediately afterwards:

> ... [W]ith the ever-varied powers of nature; — nor can I doubt but ...

Why would she do such a thing?

Comment: Possibly you have a typo in your copy: [in this one there is no dash](http://www.pagebypagebooks.com/Mary_Wollstonecraft_Shelley/Frankenstein/Letter_4_p4.html)

Comment: Perhaps they had different rules back in the days before English became the finished and perfected article. Perhaps it's a misplaced bolt.

Comment: And not in this 1818 copy either: even the wording is different. My understanding is that Shelley revised her book several times, especially after returning to England. ["...accustomed to believe impossible: _but I do 
not doubt_ that my tale conveys in its series internal evidence 
of the truth of the events of which it is composed."](https://archive.org/stream/Frankenstein1818Edition/frank-a5_djvu.txt)

Comment: could be to really mark out the phrase starting with "nor" for special emphasis.